# Using Lenses on Scala Regular Classes

Tags: scala, lenses

Most popular JSON libraries for Scala have the ability to serialize and deserialize to case classes.

Unfortunately, until Scala 2.11 is released, there is a restriction on the number of parameters a case class can have (22 maximum). As a workaround to go over this limit, it is possible to use regular classes instead. (for example: [How can I deserialize from JSON with Scala using *non-case* classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925650/how-can-i-deserialize-from-json-with-scala-using-non-case-classes)).

However, this loses the benefits of case classes. For example, there is no automatically-generated copy constructor, and lenses don't work with regular classes, so manipulating the structure becomes very cumbersome (unless one makes every field in the class a `var`, giving up on the benefits of immutability).

Is there a way to make regular classes behave more like case classes so that, for example, lenses would also work on them?

Comment: It's not really accurate to say that lenses "don't work with" regular classes. Some specific lens libraries (like [Rillit](https://github.com/akisaarinen/rillit/tree/nodynamic)) may provide nicer syntax for case classes, but `Lens` is a very simple interface, and you can always define your own.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that, by defining a copy function (unfortunately by hand), regular classes can work with lenses, as Travis mentioned in his comment to the question, above.

Below is a proof of concept that works (using json4s and a copy of an old Scalaz lens implementation, borrowed from Daniel Sobral's answer to [Cleaner way to update nested structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900307/cleaner-way-to-update-nested-structures)):

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import native.Serialization.write

class Parent(val name:String, val age:Int, val kids:List[Kid]){
  override def toString() = s"""$name is $age years old, her/his kids are ${kids.mkString(", ")}."""

  def copy(name:String = name, age:Int = age, kids:List[Kid] = kids) = 
    new Parent(name, age, kids)
}

class Kid(val name:String, val age:Int){
  override def toString() = s"""$name ($age)"""

  def copy(name:String = name, age:Int = age) = 
    new Kid(name, age)
}

object TestJson {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  val json = """{"name":"John", "age":41, "kids":[{"name":"Mary", "age":10}, {"name":"Tom", "age":7}]}"""

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val parentKidsLens = Lens(
      get = (_: Parent).kids, 
      set = (p: Parent, kids: List[Kid]) => p.copy(kids = kids))

    val firstKidLens = Lens(
      get = (_: List[Kid]).head,
      set = (kds: List[Kid], kid: Kid) => kid :: kds.tail)

    val kidAgeLens = Lens(
      get = (_: Kid).age,
      set = (k: Kid, age: Int) => k.copy(age = age))

    val parentFirstKidAgeLens = parentKidsLens andThen firstKidLens andThen kidAgeLens


    println( parentFirstKidAgeLens.mod(parse(json).extract[Parent], age => age + 1) )    
  }
}

case class Lens[A,B](get: A => B, set: (A,B) => A) extends Function1[A,B] with Immutable {
  def apply(whole: A): B   = get(whole)
  def updated(whole: A, part: B): A = set(whole, part)
  def mod(a: A, f: B => B) = set(a, f(this(a)))
  def compose[C](that: Lens[C,A]) = Lens[C,B](
    c => this(that(c)),
    (c, b) => that.mod(c, set(_, b))
  )
  def andThen[C](that: Lens[B,C]) = that compose this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using lenses anyway, just nest your case classes.  You'll have more potential for reuse of data, and the main reason not to nest is to avoid monstrosities like

```
record.copy(person = record.person.copy(name = record.person.name.capitalize))
```

which are (largely) solved if you use lenses.  JSON can handle nested classes.